# Check if Hamiltonian is $PT$ symmetric

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, parity, time-reversal-symmetry

If an Operator is $PT$ symmetric, then its Eigenvalues are real and the time evolution is unitary, just like hermitian Operators. This is described in many books and papers, but I'm not sure how to actually check if a given Hamiltonian is $PT$ symmetric or not. If $H$ has an unbroken $PT$ symmetry, then it commutes with the $PT$-Operators
\begin{align*}
[PT,H] = 0
\end{align*}
The Actions of these Operators are $P: $ x -> (-x) ; p -> (-p) and $T :$ p -> (-p) ; i -> (-i).
Lets say the Hamiltonian is given by something like the Dirac-Hamiltonian
\begin{align*}
H= \left( \begin{array}{rr}
-i\hbar c\partial_x & -mc^2 \\ 
-mc^2 & i\hbar\partial_x
\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}

How can one actually compute the commutator above? Is there a difference when $PT$ Operators act from left or right to the Hamiltonian?

Answer (score 2):

Let's write the Hamiltonian in terms of Pauli matrices.
$$H=cp_x\sigma_z-mc^2\sigma_x$$
Now
$$\hat{T}=i\sigma_y \hat{K};\, \hat{P}:p_x\rightarrow-p_x, \sigma_{x,y,z}\rightarrow \sigma_{x,y,z}$$
$\hat{K}$ being the complex conjugation operator. Therefore
$$(\hat{P} \hat{T}) H (\hat{P} \hat{T})^{-1}= -H $$
So your Hamiltonian is not invariant with respect to $\hat{P}\hat{T}$ and the commutator is non-zero.

Comment: How did you calculate $(PT)H(PT)^{-1} = -H$? Whats the action from the inverse operators from the right?

Comment: When an operator can be written as a matrix, you can take it as a regular matrix product. When there is no matrix form, this is the definition of how an operation (e.g. symmetry) acts on an operator. For example, when we say what is the effect of parity $\hat{P}$ on, say, position $\vec{r}$, you in fact imply $\hat{P}\vec{r}\hat{P}^{-1}=-\vec{r}$.

Comment: isnt it $P\vec{r}=-\vec{r}$ since the parity operator changes the sign? And if $P^{-1}$ is the inverse of $P$, it also should just change the sign of $\vec{r}$, so $P\vec{r}P^{-1}$ should be equal to $\vec{r}$ or did i get something wrong here?

Comment: No, operators act this way (on one side) on states. When transforming operators (such as $\hat{\vec{r}}$), you always have to "sandwich" them. This is most clear when you think of operators in matrix representation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you answer, this kinda helped me out. But I think I need to tell what my actual problem is. Im looking at the Dirac equation in $AdS_2$-Space. The Hamiltonian is given by:
\begin{align*}
H = \left( \begin{array}{rr}
-i\hbar c(\partial_\theta+\frac{\tan{\theta}}{2}) & -\frac{Lmc^2}{\cos{\theta}} \\ 
-\frac{Lmc^2}{\cos{\theta}} & i\hbar c(\partial_\theta+\frac{\tan{\theta}}{2})
\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}
which is clearly not hermitian because of the tangent terms. So it might have complex Eigenvalues, which means that I cant identify its Eigenvalues with the energy of the system. I found, that if the Hamilton is PT symmetric, it's Eigenvalues are real which would allow an interpretation as the energy. I assume, that $p = -i\hbar(\partial_\theta + \frac{\tan{\theta}}{2})$ is the momentum operator (reasonable assumption?) in $AdS_2$ and define $m_{eff} = \frac{Lm}{\cos{\theta}}$ to be an effective mass term. So the Hamiltonian has the form of the Dirac-Hamiltonian in Minkowski-Space above. But if its not hermitian and not PT symmetric, I have no clue how to make sense of it and it's eigenvalue problem.

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer here. Are you sure about the imaginary $tan$ term?